# Use column from CSV as a category label for plotting column chart using gnuplot

Tags: csv, gnuplot, stacked-chart

I have a CSV file looking like:

```
frameNo dataSeg paritySeg   frameType
0   17  3   k
1   2   1   d
2   3   1   d
3   3   1   d
4   3   1   d
5   2   1   d
6   3   1   d
7   3   1   d
8   4   1   d
```

I'm able to plot stacked column diagram showing number of data and parity segments per frame. Looks like this:

[image]

What I'd like to add to it, however, is paint differently those columns (both data and parity) which have "k" marker in the last column. Basically, distinguish between two categories - "d" and "k".
Is that possible using gnuplot?

Here's the script I'm using:

```
set style histogram rowstacked; 
set style data histograms; 
set style fill solid; 
set datafile separator "\t";
set terminal png size 2500,1500 enhanced font ",30";
set title "";
set tics font ",25";
set xlabel "Frame #" font ",25";
set ylabel "# of segments" font ",25";
set key outside;
set xrange [0:];
plot "segments.csv" using 2 t "Data", "" using 3 t "Parity";'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could impose a custom condition on the columns being plotted and supply an invalid value (signaling to skip the particular data point) if this condition is not met:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1200,600 enhanced font ",30";
set output 'test.png'

set style histogram rowstacked; 
set style data histograms; 
set style fill solid; 

#set datafile separator "\t";

set title "";
set tics font ",25";
set xlabel "Frame #" font ",25";
set ylabel "# of segments" font ",25";
set key outside;
set xrange [0:];

fName = 'segments.csv'

plot \
    fName using (strcol(4) eq 'd'?$2:1/0) t "Data d" lc rgb '#666666', \
    fName using (strcol(4) eq 'd'?$3:1/0) t "Parity d" lc rgb '#ff0000', \
    fName using (strcol(4) eq 'k'?$2:1/0) t "Data k" lc rgb '#000000', \
    fName using (strcol(4) eq 'k'?$3:1/0) t "Parity k" lc rgb '#990000'
```

this would give (using the sample data in your question):
[image]